# ReactJS: State is empty after setState then value is set

Tags: reactjs, fetch, array.prototype.map

Im trying to make a simple SPA just to learn reactJS. I'm trying to consume RIOT API (developer.riotgames.com) but i doesn't work!

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      riotAPIdata: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://global.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/static-data/BR/v1.2/champion?champData=image%2Cinfo%2Cstats%2Ctags&dataById=false&locale=pt_BR&api_key=RGAPI-0ed56255-77e0-4002-8e44-024f74be8249')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(riotAPI => { this.setState({ riotAPIdata: riotAPI.data }) })

  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.riotAPIdata !== {}) {
      console.log(this.state.riotAPIdata)
    } else {
      console.log("Carregando")
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="App-intro">
            {this.state.riotAPIdata.map((obj, i) => {
              return <p key={i}>{obj.name}</p>
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Console show me following errors:

[image]

First it logs twice the same line, then mapping doesnt work! any help?

Comment: The second log clearly shows that `riotAPIdata` is an **object**, not an array. Objects don't have a `.map` method. In other words, `riotAPI.data` is not an array. Solutions are: Convert the object to an array before updating the state, or find a different way to traverse the data structure. FWIW, `this.state.riotAPIdata !== {}` will always be `true` because objects are compared by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Felix Kling said in his comment is totally true, I have used something like this in past and I was able to use map, may be it might help you, try something like this in your 'componentWillMount'

```
var response_json = response.json
this.setState({riotAPIdata: response_json.data.map((val) => {
              return {
                val: val
              };
         )})
```

And then you can use the value in your render method using something like this

```
{this.state.riotAPIdata.map((obj, i) => {
          return <p key={i}>{obj.val.name}</p>
        })}
```

Like I am not sure about the structure of riotAPIdata but play around with this, it will surely work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool, then you can mark my answer for future reference :)